# SELECT query for selecting logged in users rows only - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a members only website in which the logged in users fill in an entry form which goes to a MySQL table called **'ltd_sales_list'** with the following columns:

> **ltd_item_id** | **ltd_user_id** |
>   **ltd_invoice_no** | **ltd_entry_amount** |
>   **ltd_entry_date**

For each new entry they input, a new id/primary key is generated (**'ltd_item_id'**) for each row, while their SESSION log in id is recorded in **'ltd_user_id'** while the **'ltd_entry_date'** is a timestamp. The entry form page works fine but viewing the entry data is where I am having the issue.

I have put together the code below called **view-list.php** but this calls up every user's entry list. What I am trying to do is show the **logged in user's entry list only**.

I think the answer lies within the queries somewhere and have tried some WHERE statements with ltd_user_id = $_SESSION['ltd_user_id'] and similar but for no success.

If anyone could help or could point me to some links that would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php 

require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');

$page_title = 'Page Title';
include ('./includes/header.html');

if (!isset($_SESSION['ltd_user_id'])) {

   $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

   if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
        $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); 
   }

   $url .= '/login.php'; 
ob_end_clean(); 
header("Location: $url"); 
exit(); 
}
?>

<div id="">HTML Content HERE</div>

<?php

echo '<h1>My Entry Log</h1>';

require_once ('/server/database_connection.php'); // Connect to the db.

$display = 10;

if (isset($_GET['np'])) { 
    $num_pages = $_GET['np'];
} else { 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ltd_sales_list ORDER BY ltd_entry_date DESC";   
    $result = @mysql_query ($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
    $num_records = $row[0];

    if ($num_records > $display) { 
       $num_pages = ceil ($num_records/$display);
    } else {
       $num_pages = 1;
    }
} 

if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

$link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lna";
$link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fna";
$link3 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=dra";

if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {

    switch ($_GET['sort']) {
       case 'lna':
          $order_by = 'ltd_invoice_no ASC';
          $link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lnd";
          break;
       case 'lnd':
          $order_by = 'ltd_invoice_no DESC';
          $link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lna";
          break;
       case 'fna':
          $order_by = 'ltd_entry_amount ASC';
          $link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fnd";
          break;
       case 'fnd':
          $order_by = 'ltd_entry_amount DESC';
          $link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fna";
          break;
       case 'dra':
          $order_by = 'ltd_entry_date ASC';
          $link3 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=drd";
          break;
       case 'drd':
          $order_by = 'ltd_entry_date DESC';
          $link3 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=dra";
          break;   
       default:
          $order_by = 'ltd_entry_date DESC';
          break;
    }

    $sort = $_GET['sort'];

} else { 
    $order_by = 'ltd_entry_date DESC';
    $sort = 'dra';
}

$query = "SELECT ltd_invoice_no, ltd_entry_amount,  
    DATE_FORMAT(ltd_entry_date, '%M %d, %Y') AS dr, ltd_user_id FROM ltd_sales_list ORDER BY
    $order_by LIMIT $start, $display";
$result = @mysql_query ($query); 

echo '<table width="520" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="11">
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b><a href="' . $link1 . '">Invoice Number</a></b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><a href="' . $link2 . '">Invoice Amount</a></b></td>
 <td align="left"><b><a href="' . $link3 . '">Date Entered</a></b></td>
</tr>
';

$bg = '#eeeeee'; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $bg = ($bg=='#eaeced' ? '#ffffff' : '#eaeced');  
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
       <td align="left">' . $row['ltd_invoice_no'] . '</td>
       <td align="left">' . $row['ltd_entry_amount'] . '</td>
       <td align="left">' . $row['dr'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
echo '</table>';
mysql_free_result ($result); 
mysql_close(); 

if ($num_pages > 1) {
    echo '<br /><p>';
    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    if ($current_page != 1) {
       echo '<a href="view-list.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&np=' .
         $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">Previous</a> ';   
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
       if ($i != $current_page) {
          echo '<a href="view-list.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . 
            '&np=' . $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">' . $i . '</a> ';   
       } else {
          echo $i . ' ';
       }
    }
    if ($current_page != $num_pages) {
       echo '<a href="view-list.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&np=' . 
         $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">Next</a> ';   
    }

    echo '</p>';

} 

?>

<div id="">HTML Content HERE</div>

<?php
include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Cheers
Adam

Comment: Are you calling session_start() before trying to access session variables?  I'd suggest you verify that you're able to access the correct user ID, then work from there.

Comment: Oops! The session_start(); is in the header.html include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be as simple as escaping everything, exiting from the quotes when doing variables? It looks to me like it should work. Can you vardump the $_SESSION['ltd_user_id'] somewhere to make sure it is behaving as expected?

```
$query = "SELECT `ltd_invoice_no`, `ltd_entry_amount`,  
DATE_FORMAT(`ltd_entry_date`, '%M %d, %Y') AS `dr`, `ltd_user_id` FROM `ltd_sales_list` WHERE `ltd_user_id` = '".$_SESSION['ltd_user_id']."' ORDER BY
".$order_by." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$display;
```

Comment: Cool! It is a good practice to always exit out of the quotes when going into variables. It keeps the code legible. The SQL variable name quotes allow you to not run the risk of accidentally naming one of your columns after a function, confusing the hell out of the database.